# join query within same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table `errorflag` where following is the data

```
+-----+-----+-------+
| ID  | NO  | Error |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 200 | 100 |     1 |
| 201 | 100 |     0 |
| 202 |  98 |     1 |
| 203 |  98 |     1 |
| 204 |  99 |     1 |
| 205 |  87 |     1 |
| 206 |  87 |     0 |
| 207 |  90 |     1 |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

i would like to have data output as below

```
No

98
99
90
```

when the Number is repeated in field 'NO' and error is 1 and 0 than i want to exclude from result.

I am struggling with joins and having count query.

Comment: So just to clarify, you only want to show `NO` where it has no `Error = 0`?

Comment: @Martin, I think the opposite - only show `NO` when `Error = 1` for all instances of `NO`. For example, `NO = 100` is excluded in the desired output.

Comment: in column 'No' is repeated and error flag is 0 than i would like to exclude from the final result. as in this case 100 has error 1 and 0 so i don't want to have it in final result, but 98 has error 1 in both rows so i wan to include it in final result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what is being asked.

If I am right in thinking you only want `NO` values where there is no `0` for the error, then this should do the trick:

```
SELECT `NO`
  FROM errorflag
  WHERE `NO` NOT IN (
                  SELECT `NO`
                    FROM errorflag 
                    WHERE Error = 0)
  GROUP BY `NO`
```

Output:

```
NO
90
98
99
```

Sqlfiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e088fb/4).

Comment: The question is tagged SQL Server, but the backticks `\`` make this MySQL specific. I guess the question should be retagged for MySQL?

Comment: it is for sql server .

Answer (score 2):

```
select  distinct no
from    YourTable yt1
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt1.no = yt2.no
                and yt2.error = 0
        )
```

[Example at dbfiddle.co.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ef2834c8022335a8868f8e63c7f506c9)

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this in a single query if you use aggregate functions. Based on your described environment, `Error` can only hold the value of 0 or 1. Thus you could just group by `NO` and ensure that the minimum value for `Error` is never zero.

```
SELECT NO FROM TableName
GROUP BY NO
HAVING MIN(Error) <> 0
```

Comment: I think I would say `= 1`, but the idea is the same.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I originally wrote it as `=  1` but I thought perhaps `!= 0` would be more appropriate in cases where error codes go beyond the range of 0 and 1.

Comment: That's a nice way to do it! The standard way to write not equal is `<>` I think, not `!=`

Answer (score 0):

could be you can check for errono count = 2 and distinct error = 2

```
  select e.* from errorflag e
  left join (
    select  errono, count(*) num_err_no, count(distinct error) count_error 
    from errorflag 
    group by errono 
    having count(*) =2 and count_error = 2
  ) t on t.errorno = e.errorno 
  where t.errorno is null
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `error` flag has always `0` or `1` then you use `not exists` :

```
select ef.*
from errorflag ef
where not exists (select 1 
                  from errorflag ef1 
                  where ef1.no = ef.no and ef1.error <> ef.error
                 );
```

For only single column then only aggregation is enough :

```
select no
from errorflag ef
group by no
having count(distinct error) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

to exclude IDs where a 01 pair exists for NO - try the following

```
SELECT DISTINCT NO FROM errorflag  
WHERE ID NOT IN 
            (SELECT e1.ID FROM errorflag e1 
                        JOIN errorflag e2 
                            ON (e1.Error = 0 And e2.error = 1 or e2.Error = 0 And e1.error = 1) AND e1.[No] = e2.[no]
            )
```

is there am maximum of 2 errors per NO?

Could you get errors 0,1,1 for NO 99 for example?

see here with a change

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2d2cf5/3

Comment: no, that case will never exist. there is only 0 or 1

Comment: in that case, I'm hoping that my code will exclude any ID that is part of a {0,1} pair for its NO

Comment: thanks for your input but it didn't works. check [link] http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9dd35/1

Comment: that seems to exclude 100 which has {1,0} - but it includes 101 and 110 which don't - seemed to be what you asked - good luck with project!